# Doxygen: How to output image references in xml format

Tags: xml, image, doxygen

In Doxygen, is there a way to output a reference to the images in xml format too?

`CLASS_DIAGRAMS` option is described to output images in html and latex as stated below.

> If the CLASS_DIAGRAMS tag is set to YES, doxygen will generate a class diagram (in HTML and LaTeX)...

Comment: Did you try to set GENERATE_XML and see what happens? (I didn't test or look into the code, so I don't know if it works or not).

Comment: Yes, I'm generating both xml and html, image references are only output in html.